# How to resolve shape incompatibility when training a TensorFlow convolutional variational autoencoder?

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph, shapes, autoencoder

I am trying to build a convolutional variational autoencoder in order to train it with signals of power over time, so that it can classify whether the signals are correct or not. When i use the model.fit function I have the following problem :

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Node: 'gradient_tape/lambda/mul_1/BroadcastGradientArgs'
Incompatible shapes: [12313] vs. [1576064]
[[{{node gradient_tape/lambda/mul_1/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_7528]

Here is the code I've written :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from pickle import TRUE
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanSquaredError
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

dfs = []
for i in range(1, 8) :
    filename = f"C:/Users/X/Desktop/signaux/{i}.csv"
    df=pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=';')
    df=df.loc[ : , ['w']]
    dfs.append(df)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
dfff = []
for df in dfs :
    df_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(df.values.reshape(-1, 1))
    dfff.append(df_scaled)
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
    print(df_scaled)

# Find the length of the longest signal
max_len = max([len(df_scaled.flatten()) for df_scaled in dfff])

# Pad all signals with zeros to make them of equal length so that we can feed them to the neural network
padded_signals = []
for df_scaled in dfff:
    signal = df_scaled.flatten()
    padded_signal = np.pad(signal, (0, max_len - len(signal)), 'constant')
    padded_signals.append(padded_signal)

# Concatenate all signals into one numpy array
concatenated_signals = np.concatenate(padded_signals)

# Here we change the shape of the input to a 3d one in order not to lose the temporal information.
num_samples = len(padded_signals)
time_steps = max_len
input_dim = 1
reshaped_signals = concatenated_signals.reshape(num_samples, time_steps, input_dim)
reshaped_signals = np.expand_dims(reshaped_signals, axis=0)

height = num_samples
width = time_steps
channels = input_dim
latent_dim = 30
x_train=reshaped_signals
y_true=reshaped_signals
epochs=30
batch_size=1
print(x_train.shape)
print(y_true.shape)

def make_encoder_model() :

    input_shape = (height, width, channels)
    #input_shape= (1,7,1759,1)
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=1, padding='same')(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(x)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=2, padding='same')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(x)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=2, padding='same')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(x)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=2, padding='same')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(x)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)

    z_mean = tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim)(x)
    z_log_var = tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim)(x)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var])

def make_decoder_model():
    input_shape = (2*latent_dim,)
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(width * height * channels)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((width, height, channels))(x)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)

    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=channels, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=2, padding='same', activation='sigmoid')(x)

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

def my_loss(y_true, y_pred, decoder) :
    y_pred = K.reshape(y_pred, shape=(-1, 7, 1759, 1))
    z_mean, z_log_var = encoder(y_pred)
    z = z_mean + K.exp(z_log_var / 2) * K.random_normal(shape=K.shape(z_mean))
    z = tf.reshape(z, shape=(-1,60))
    reconstructed = decoder(z)
    reconstruction_loss = keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(K.flatten(y_true), K.flatten(reconstructed))
    #reconstruction_loss *= height * width
    kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var)
    kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
    kl_loss *= -0.5
    vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
    return vae_loss

# Creation of encoder and decoder
encoder = make_encoder_model()
decoder = make_decoder_model()

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(height, width, channels))

z_mean, z_log_var = encoder(inputs)

z = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([z_mean, z_log_var])

outputs = decoder(z)
vae = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
vae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=lambda y_true, y_pred: my_loss(y_true, y_pred, decoder))
vae.fit(x_train, y_true, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
```